# Average of specific cells with numbers determined by multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to create a formula on the first screenshot that references the cells in the second screenshot based on the name and week number. In the second screenshot, which shows data from the "HVL" tab, you can see the associate's name on the left and the week numbers across the top as the column headers. Because the week number appears more than once is where I believe I'm having the issue. The 100% that you see in the cell is not correct according to the data in the "HVL" tab. Here are some formulas that I've tried using:

```
=AVERAGE(((HVL!$A$2:$A$144='Weekly Report Card'!$C$1)*(HVL!$B$1:$AG$1='Weekly Report Card'!$A6)*(HVL!$C$3:$AG$201<>0)))

=AVERAGE(IF(HVL!A2:A144='Weekly Report Card'!C1:H1, IF(HVL!B1:AG1='Weekly Report Card'!A6, HVL!C3:AG201<>0, "ERROR")))
```

Both as an array and as normal.

```
=AVERAGEIF(HVL!$A$2:$A$144, "<>", INDEX(HVL!$C$3:$AG$201, MATCH($C$1, HVL!$A$2:$A$144, 0), MATCH('Weekly Report Card'!$A8, HVL!$C$1:$AG$1, 0)))
```

Both as an array and as normal.

If there's any other information that you need, please let me know.

[[image: Weekly Report Card][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcBy7.png)

[image: HVL]

Comment: Sample file containing both tabs if wanted:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24151931/Sample%20File.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in cell C6 on the weekly report card.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(HVL!$C$2:$C$50,MATCH('weekly report card'!$C$1,HVL!$A$2:$A$50)):INDEX(HVL!$AG2:$AG$50,MATCH('weekly report card'!$C$1,HVL!$A$2:$A$50)),HVL!$C$1:$AG$1,'weekly report card'!$A6)
```

The first Index/Match establishes the row in column C where the name is found. The second Index/Match establishes the row in column AG where the name is found. The `:` operator creates a range from column C to AG in that row.

This range is plugged into AverageIfs, where it is compared against the week number in row 1.

Comment: I tried using your formula but am getting a #VALUE error message for week 28 when using the name Alex Arredondo from the name list. There is data for that week but only on one day while the rest are blank. At which point should I enter an extra criteria to eliminate the blank spaces?

Comment: AverageIFs ignores blank cells or text. Step through the formula with the Evaluate Formula tool and see where the error occurs. Then correct formula or data as required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula that worked for my file:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(HVL!$C$1:$AG$1,$A6,INDEX(HVL!$C$3:$AG$202,MATCH($C$1,HVL!$A$3:$A$202,0),0)),"")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the Average-If-Series function:  AVERAGEIFS